# Find the two-dimensional random distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I need to find the two-dimensional distribution $(\xi_1,\xi_2)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, that for any $a,b$ the random variable $\chi = a\xi_1 + b\xi_2$ has  density only if $ab\neq0$.
distribution shouldn't depend of $a$ or $b$.

Can u help me to understand what means random variable without density?

Comment: It probably means that when $ab = 0$ the density is set equal to zero.

Comment: How can i find density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have some doubts about what conditions this joint density must fulfill (your English are a bit vague), let's try this.  Instead of $\xi$ I will use $y$.

So we want to determine a joint probability density function $f_{Y_1Y_2}(y_1,y_2)$ such that

a) It does not contain the constants $a, b$
b) The probability density function of the r.v. $X = aY_1 + bY_2$ is defined (i.e it is not defined as zero), only when $ab\neq 0$.

The answer is (perhaps not unique): $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ must be  *independent*, in which case their joint probability density function is the product of the marginal densities
$$ f_{Y_1Y_2}(y_1,y_2) = f_{Y_1}(y_1)f_{Y_2}(y_2) $$

Condition a) is satisfied since we can say that $a$ and $b$ are not included in the above.

To show that condition b) is also satisfied, we proceed as follows:
Define the "intermediate" variables $Z_1 = aY_1$, $Z_2 = bY_2$.
Then by the change-of variable formula we obtain
$$ f_{Z_1}(z_1) = \frac 1af_{Y_1}\left(\frac {z_1}{a}\right),\qquad f_{Z_2}(z_2) = \frac 1bf_{Y_2}\left(\frac {z_2}{b}\right) $$

Given the definition of the $Z$-variables, we have
$$X = Z_1 + Z_2$$
The cummulative distribution function of $X$ is defined as $P(Z_1 + Z_2\le x)$ which gives the inequality $z_1 \le x-z_2$. Now *given the independence* of the $Y$-variables, the $Z$-variables are also independent. Then, the probability density function of $X$ is given by the convolution

$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Z_1}(x-z_2)f_{Z_2}(z_2)dz_2$$

Using the previous results we have

$$f_X(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac 1af_{Y_1}\left(\frac {x-z_2}{a}\right)\frac 1bf_{Y_2}\left(\frac {z_2}{b}\right) dz_2$$
$$\Rightarrow f_X(x) = \frac {1}{ab}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y_1}\left(\frac {x-z_2}{a}\right)f_{Y_2}\left(\frac {z_2}{b}\right) dz_2 $$

It is obvious that this probability density "can be defined" only when $ab\neq 0$ which is what we wanted to show.

It is the *independence assumption related to the $Y$-variables* that permitted us to arrive at this result, without the need to actually specify a functional form for their joint probability density function, or for their marginals.